# Laravel 4: detect requested Route in "before" filter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I need to detect requested Route from filter (run before the Route), tried:

```
Route::getCurrentRoute();
```

seems not working in before filters

how to get requested route?

thanks,

Comment: I use `Route::current()` in my role-based validation, and that works without any issues

Comment: Route::current() not return any value in before filter

Comment: Does it error? (check the laravel log) or does it simply return a null (would suggest some configuration issue)

Comment: `Route::current()` should return a `Illuminate\Routing\Route` Object . You can then access the path with `Route::current()->getPath()`

Answer (score 3):

You can access the requested uri / path through the [request object](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Http.Request.html) passed through the filters closure.

```
Route::filter('filtername', function($route, $request)
{
    echo $request->path();
    echo $route->getPath();
    echo $request->url();
});
```

Comment: can you expand on what you mean by *partially* ?